# Formatting a dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, disk-formatting

I have a dual boot system: Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.10. Now I would like to erase everything, and install a fresh copy of Windows, and then add Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

What do I need to do to make sure both the operating systems are gone when I format the hard disk?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  When you format/mkfs your hdd/sdd, you'll be erasing whatever was there before (be it windows 7 or Ubuntu 16.10). You don't need to do anything before the mkfs/format; data on your drive will remain only if you leave part of your drive(s) un-formatted.  If you want to ensure delete, you could always re-create partition table...

Comment: So, the format process will delete both Windows and Ubuntu, and I don't need to delete Ubuntu from Windows first?

Comment: Is this a newer UEFI system or older BIOS based system? If UEFI be sure ot install both systems in same UEFI boot mode. Or if BIOS default will be BIOS installs, but last installed system will be in MBR as default boot. So then better to install Windows first.

Comment: I think it's an older BIOS system. The last time I formatted my laptop, it had Windows 7 only. To do so, I restart the computer, and press one of the F keys to start the formatting process, and that's it. Now, I have a dual boot, and all I want to do is to have one partition for a new copy of Windows. I know how to install Ubuntu later, but I just want to know if following the same procedure as I did before the dual boot will erase both Windows and Ubuntu, and I will have all the hard desk space again.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by using one of the F keys (I assume function keys, but is the key being processed by your machine's BIOS or a running OS??)  If it's your machine BIOS, then it's machine specific, and a hardware question which is likely off-topic. You need to check with whatever program/tool that is being run when you press the 'F' key.

Comment: Yes, F key is one of the function keys to start the formatting process when I restart the laptop. The question is not about the formatting process itself (not machine specific, I can search which F key I use. I forgot because it was a long time ago), but about whether having a dual boot will need any extra steps, or it's the same as if I had Windows alone.